# Is there a way to increase the timeout value for Dynamics CRM server invocation?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am write a simple application to test the Linq query functionality provided by CRMSDK.

My code is simple enough.

```
     var before = DateTime.Now;
     var crm = new Stub.Xrm.MyDataContext("MyCRM");
     var contact = crm.contacts.FirstOrDefault();
     var span = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks-before.Ticks);
     Console.WriteLine("The name is " + contact.name);
     Console.WriteLine("It took " + span.Seconds + " seconds to run this program " );
```

It took about one minute to run but it worked.
Then I try to query different entity such as account, I got the

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
```

I am suspecting this happens because I had more accounts then contacts, so it took longer to process account query. I am trying to increase the timeout value at my app.config by  but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout does not happen in your application. The timeout happens on the server side. Therefore you *could* increase it there.

Is there a special reason why you would load **all** records at once and take **only** the first of the sequence?

You should never have a request with an [unbounded result set.](http://ayende.com/blog/4785/what-am-i-so-hung-up-on-unbounded-result-set) 
If you have 500k accounts in your system, the query will return all of them (including all their filled properties).

Comment: To my understanding of Linq, the crm.contacts statement does NOT bring back all records. It does not get executed until the .FirstOrDefault() gets called. So, the linq provider translates the whole statement into something like select top(1) * from contacts; Anyway, the example I gave was just trying to test if Linq works. It turned out that the start-up time is very slow, but it takes less than one second after the first query. I am now wondering why the startup time is so long.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout values in the web.config of CRM.

Answer (score 0):

To increase CRM timeout, you can use two approaches:

1. Server side

    Check out this ['A time-out occurs when you import large customization files into Microsoft Dynamics CRM'](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918609)
2. Client side

    if you use service proxy as the connection scenario, you can set the Timeout property. Here is the sample:

   _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
   var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); // add 10 minutes
   _serviceProxy.Timeout = timeout;

   Hope this help.